# DJANGO MEDIA_URL returns to same page instead of showing image

Tags: python, django

There are lots of answer on how to upload media files, what are the correct configuration and how to serve it on our application.

But my project seems to work nothing.

The aim is simple: User uploads an image. Django displays it on.

**models.py**

```
class UploadImageModel(models.Model):
image = models.FileField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include("Image.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .forms import UploadImageModelForm
from .models import UploadImageModel
# Create your views here.

class UploadImage(View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UploadImageModelForm()
    context = {
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UploadImageModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.title = str(instance.image)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "instance":instance,
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Static")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Media")
```

**index.html**

```
{% if instance.image %}
    <img src="{{instance.image.url}}" alt="Image"/>
{% endif %}
```

ERROR: After uploading an image named `<something>.jpg`, if I visit, `127.0.0.1:8000/media/1.jpeg`, browser does not displays image, instead it shows `index.html` page.

[image]

SO how to serve this media file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is a catch-all for every URL:

```
url(r'', include("Image.urls")),
```

Without seeing the contents of `Image/urls.py` I can only suggest replacing that line with an explicit pattern that executes the index view, such as:

```
url(r'^$', my_index_view),
```